# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x60A9B49C (msvcr110d.dll)

Tags: c

Подскажите, пожалуйста с чем может быть связана связана ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x51F8B49C (msvcr110d.dll) в Проект2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xCCCCCCCC.

Листинг кода:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<clocale>
#include<Windows.h>

struct STUDENT {
    char fio[21];
    int grup;
    int oc1;
    int oc2;
    int oc3;
    int oc4;
    bool zach1;
    bool zach2;
    bool zach3;
    bool zach4;
    bool zach5;
};

void NeusSt(int k, STUDENT * ms);
void srBal(int k, STUDENT * ms);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    int i;
    FILE *f;
    struct STUDENT ms[300];
    if ((f = fopen("students.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        puts("Файл не найден.");
    for (i = 0; !feof(f); i++) {
        fgets(ms[i].fio, 15, f);
        fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", ms[i].grup, ms[i].oc1, ms[i].oc2, ms[i].oc3, ms[i].oc4, ms[i].zach1, ms[i].zach2, ms[i].zach3, ms[i].zach4, ms[i].zach5);
    }
    int k = i;                        // номер последнего считанного элемента массива m
    char c;
    do {
        system("cls");                //заметить на clrscr(); для компиляторов не VisualStudio
        //clrsrc();
        puts("==========================================");
        puts("Выберите действие:");
        puts("1-показать неуспевающих студентов");
        puts("2-определить средний балл одной из групп");
        c = getchar();
        switch (c) {
        case 1:
            NeusSt(k, ms);
            break;
        case 2:
            srBal(k, ms);
            break;
        }
        getchar();
    } while (c = '4');
}

void NeusSt(int k, STUDENT * ms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        int zad = 0;
        bool net = 0;
        if (ms[i].oc1 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].oc2 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].oc3 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].oc4 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].zach1 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].zach2 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].zach3 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].zach4 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (ms[i].zach5 == 0)
            zad++;
        if (zad > 0) {
            printf("%s группы №%d имеет - %d задолжностей", ms[i].fio, ms[i].grup, zad);
            net = 1;
        }
        if (net == 0)
            puts("В группе нет неуспевающих студентов");
    }

    puts("Для возрата к меню нажмите любую клавишу...");
    getchar();
}

void srBal(int k, STUDENT * ms)
{
    puts("Введите номер группы:");
    int nomer;
    float srStud[30];
    int kolvo = 0;
    float ocGrup = 0;
    scanf("%d", &nomer);
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        if (nomer = ms[i].grup)
            srStud[i] = (ms[i].oc1 + ms[i].oc2 + ms[i].oc3 + ms[i].oc4) / 4;
        printf("%s средняя оценка-1.%f", ms[i].fio, srStud[i]);
        kolvo++;
        ocGrup = ocGrup + srStud[i];
    }
    float srOcGrup = ocGrup / kolvo;
    printf("Средний балл группы в целом - %d", srOcGrup);
    puts("Для возрата к меню нажмите любую клавишу...");
    getchar();
}
```

Я написал код вот к этой задачке.

> Дан файл, содержащий сведения о сдаче студентами сессии. Структура записи файла: Фио студента, номер группы; оценки по четырем экзаменам и пяти зачетам;
>
> 1. Написать программу, выдающую фамилии неуспевающих студентов с указанием номеров групп и количество задолженностей
> 2. Определение среднего балла полученным каждым студентом группы Х и всей группой в целом.
>
>    содержимое файла для тестов students.txt

```
    >     Барабанов А.А.     1233 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 0
    >     Балалайкин В.В.    1233 4 2 4 0 0 0 0 1 0  
    >     Бурундуков А.Д.    3122 3 2 5 5 1 0 0 0 1
    >     Бандурин Т.Д.      2423 5 3 4 5 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Попробуйте запустить в дебагере, он строчку укажет. Заодно значения переменных в этот момент посмотрите. 

Или хотя бы печати набросайте побольше, чтобы понять в каком месте валится.

А так, наверное где то здесь

    for (i = 0; !feof(f); i++) {

в цикле i становится больше размера какого-нибудь массива.

Comment: @avp спасибо за совет проверил.В самом коде у меня кроме массива структуры STUDENT ms других массивов нет. В дебагере какие-то не известные мне переменные: http://s019.radikal.ru/i640/1212/2a/9e08a4a56ffe.png, причём среди них i нет.

Comment: @Carpoff, я уже нашел и отписал в ответе, а потом глянул Ваш url "от дебагера". Там вообщето написано, что падает в `fscanf`, только почему-то в main строка 20? 

В коде в вопросе fscanf явно дальше 20-й строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Carpoff](/users/10611/carpoff), посмотрел чуть внимательней. Как говорится, "элементарно, Ватсон".

Во первых в  fscanf()

```
fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", ms[i].grup, ms[i].oc1, ms[i].oc2, ms[i].oc3, ms[i].oc4, ms[i].zach1, ms[i].zach2, ms[i].zach3, ms[i].zach4, ms[i].zach5);
```

естественно надо передавать **адреса** полей структуры. Т.е.

```
fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &ms[i].grup, &ms[i].oc1, &ms[i].oc2, &ms[i].oc3, &ms[i].oc4, &ms[i].zach1, &ms[i].zach2, &ms[i].zach3, &ms[i].zach4, &ms[i].zach5);
```

А вот со вторым (чтение фамилии) сложнее. Да, Вы читаете первые 14 символов в ms[i].fio, но **только для первой строки** это работает, т.к. после fscanf() для первой строки в ней **останется** '\n', который прочтет fgets() на второй итерации, а дальше fscanf() вместо чисел получит буквы и все (работать не будет).

Т.о. после fscanf() надо прочесть конец строки (сделать еще раз fgets() в какой-нибудь буфер или в цикле читать fgetc() до '\n').

Вообще же жесткий формат (числа после 15-ой позиции) - это как-то некрасиво. Попробуйте читать фамилию как-то по другому, например до первой цифры. Потом ее (цифру) можно вернуть обратно в поток вызвав ungetc().

Answer (score 0):

0xCCCCCCCC - неинициализированный адрес, ищите, где такой попадается и все падает. В отладчике переменная pointer содержит именно это значение, но не понятно, откуда она в коде.

Дальше, вы совершенно точно можете сказать, падает до "Выберите действие:" или после. Так же посмотрите, не выходит ли ms[i] за границу массива, а лучше сделайте проверку.

Можете приложить файл с данными студентов, чтобы это можно было потестировать.

Comment: @mikelsv, падает до "выберете действие". Изменил условия так как написал KoVadim, поэтому ms[i], вряд ли должен переходить за границу массива. Спасибо, что предложили протестировать.

Answer (score 0):

С большой вероятностью проблема в этой строке

```
for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
```

условие нужно изменить на `i < k`

Условие

```
for (i = 0; !feof(f); i++) {
```

нужно улучшить до

```
for (i = 0; !feof(f) || i >= 299; i++) {
```

Comment: @KoVadim,к сожалению, не помогло=(

Comment: Падает в первом же fscanf(). У вас студия этого не показывает?

Решение:  fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &ms[i].grup, &ms[i].oc1, &ms[i].oc2, &ms[i].oc3, &ms[i].oc4, &ms[i].zach1, &ms[i].zach2, &ms[i].zach3, &ms[i].zach4, &ms[i].zach5);

Не хватало & перед переменными. Посмотрел в примерах, поправил, заработало.

Еще: надо писать case '1': или 49. getchar() вернет код '1' - 49. С 2 аналогично.

Comment: а кто сказал, что я под студией запускал? и какая студия под линукс:)

а scanf - да, это больное место.

Comment: @mikelsv, спасибо, я очень глупо ошибся.